# I've had 5 cups of coffee today. Does this mean I'll have more?

Tags: present-perfect, past-simple

Is it true that if I say: "I've had 5 cups of coffee today" I intend to drink more today and if I say: "I had 5 cups of coffee today" I am not going to drink any more coffee today?

I find this really confusing, because present perfect talks about what has happened until now. If I've had 5 cups of coffee today, it will remain true until the end of the day even if I'm not going to drink any more coffee.

Comment: There isnt really a way to tell whether one intends to drink more coffee today if you use "have had" I think. Read EllieK's comment v

Comment: *I have had five cups of coffee today,* does not mean you intend to drink more.  It only means that you **might** drink more.  If you have had five cups of coffee today, that will remain true until the end of the day.  However, when we tell other people how much coffee we drank today we tell the *total* amount to this moment.  If I drank ten cups of coffee today, I can say *I drank two cups of coffee today*, which is true but inaccurate in the context of discussing coffee drinking.

Comment: @EllieK 'I have had five cups of coffee today' does not 'mean' that you might have more. Of course, it is trivially true that you 'might' do anything later today but the words quoted do not contain any implication either way.

Comment: @anouk - if you drink ten cups of coffee today, saying afterwards 'I have drunk five cups of coffee' is true in a certain sense, but misleading and unnatural.

Comment: @EllieK Any reason you chose the past simple: "I drank ten cups of coffee today"?

Comment: @anouk I find "I **had** five cups of coffee today" unnatural.  *Had* is the past tense, but *today* implies the present, or an ongoing event.   You might say "I had five cups of coffee yesterday", because that is entirely in the past, but not "today".

Comment: @stangdon - It would only be natural if you were reporting your intake of coffee at the end of the day.

Comment: @Kate Bunting But even if it is the end of the day you have had 5 cups that day. Or is past simple the only possibility at the end of the day?

Comment: I meant that a late hour when you were definitely not going to have another cup is the **only** time that it makes sense to use 'I had' with 'today' (in response to stangdon's comment that it was unnatural).

Comment: @Kate Bunting Yes, but could I still say: "I've had 5 cups today" when it is the end of the day and I'm not going to drink any more?

Comment: Yes, certainly you could.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Confused! Are there any differences between "I have to go", "I had to go", "I've had to go", "I get to go", "I got to go", "I've got to go"?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/78181/confused-are-there-any-differences-between-i-have-to-go-i-had-to-go-ive)

Comment: @PeterJennings how is this question a duplicate of the older one you selected? How is **I've had (I had) five coffees today** related to **I've had/got (I had) to go**. That both posts are confused over the same tenses does not qualify it as being a duplicate. The *meanings* are quite different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.
If you say *I had five cups of coffee today* it suggests that you don't intend to drink more, but does not definitely imply it.

If you say *I have had five cups of coffee today* it says absolutely nothing about whether you may have more or not.

Comment: The crucial word to imply you will / might have *more* coffee today is ***already***. In which context it's worth noting that it's perfectly natural to append / include ***already*** in Present Perfect *I've **already** had five cups of coffee today*, but it's not really idiomatic to do this with your first (Simple Past) version.

Comment: @Colin Fine So it is perfectly fine to say: "I've had 5 cups of coffee today" even if you don't intend to drink more today?

Comment: @anouk: yes, that's perfectly fine.